# Does Google reCaptcha use session?

Tags: php, captcha, recaptcha

I was using a captcha package called visualCaptcha in my php web app. But when I use it cross domain (front end and back end are in different domains) captcha sessions were not working.
So I am planning to use [Google reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha). Does it use sessions? I couldn't find the answer in docs. I need a solution without using sessions. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Surprised to see that there are no answers (even comments)!. Anyway I have implemented this and confirmed that reCaptcha is NOT using session. Verification is done using API.